# Teria como Esconder o ScrollBars do TListView?

Tags: delphi-10

Teria como **Retira** ou **Desativar** ou **Esconder** o *ScrollBars* vertical do `TListView` não achei uma opção para isso no *Object Inspector*.

Quando ponho na `ViewStyle` `vsReport` aparece uma *ScrollBars* na Vertical queria que ela ficasse escondida mais quando rolar com o mouse ele atuasse como se o *ScrollBars* estivesse lá.

Ps: Estou utilizando Delphi 10.2 e aceito sugestão de outros componentes que funcionem parecido com o `TListView`

Comment: Tem como fazer mas O mode que sei não funciona com o mouse....

Answer (score 1):

Eu fiz assim e funciona a questão de sumir com as barras de rolagem do `TListView`
o problema é que com esses comando você consegue rolar os itens com o teclado com o mouse não funciona...

```
private
    FListViewWndProc: TWndMethod;
    procedure ListViewWndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
public
   { Private declarations }
    FShowHoriz: Boolean;
    FShowVert: Boolean;
end;

implementation

procedure TForm1.ListViewWndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  ShowScrollBar(ListView1.Handle, SB_HORZ, FShowHoriz);
  ShowScrollBar(ListView1.Handle, SB_VERT, FShowVert);
  FListViewWndProc(Msg); // mensagem do processo
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FShowHoriz           := False;                // esconder a barra de rolagem horiz
  FShowVert            := False;                // esconder a barra de rolagem vert       
  FListViewWndProc     := ListView1.WindowProc; // salvar janela antiga proc
  ListView1.WindowProc := ListViewWndProc;      // subclass
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListView1.WindowProc := FListViewWndProc; // restaurar o proc da janela
  FListViewWndProc     := nil;
end;
```